# Optimization with symmetric matrix constraint

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Consider the following optimization problem:

''Minimize some objective $f(A)$ over all matrices $A$ s.t. $A \mathbf{1} = \mathbf{1}$ and $A = A^T$.''

I wonder in which ways one can handle the symmetry constraint.

**A)** One way would be to introduce a Lagrange-multiplier $\mu_{ij}$ for each matrix entry, i.e., the Lagrangian would appear as

$\mathcal{L}(A, \lambda_i, \mu_{ij}) = (something) - \lambda^T (A\mathbf{1} - \mathbf{1}) - \sum_{i,j} \mu_{ij} (A(i,j) - A(j, i))$.

But this complicates the latter a lot, since one has to deal with all these $\mu_{ij}$'s.

**B)** Another way is shown by the following example, which I do not fully understand: Therein, the constraints are modified to ''s.t. $A \mathbf{1} = \mathbf{1}$ an $A^T \mathbf{1} = \mathbf{1}$ and $A = A^T$'', for which the Lagrangian is deriven as follows:

$\mathcal{L}(A, \lambda_i, \mu_i) = (something) - \lambda^T (A\mathbf{1} - \mathbf{1}) - \mu^T (A^T \mathbf{1} - \mathbf{1})$

So the symmetry constraint is not yet involved. Now they state that from symmetry $A = A^T$ it follows that $\lambda = \mu$, so they get

$\mathcal{L}(A, \lambda_i) = (something) - \lambda^T (A\mathbf{1} - \mathbf{1}) - \lambda^T (A^T \mathbf{1} - \mathbf{1})$

Unfortunately, it is not clear to me why $\lambda = \mu$ follows.

**C)** Are there other ways? Can one for example just ignore the symmetry constraint in the Lagrangian and bring in the symmetry at any other point later?

---

So, to clearify my question: Could somebody please enlight me with the reasoning in B) and/or explain other useful strategies to respect the symmetric matrix constraint?

Comment: You could rewrite A) as $\text{Tr}(\Lambda(A-A^T))$.

Comment: Sorry for delayed the comment. Is it possible to provide a reference of the constrained problem you are talking about?

Comment: Luckily I was able to remember :) See the proof of Proposition 2 at the very last page of the following NIPS-paper "https://papers.nips.cc/paper/3049-doubly-stochastic-normalization-for-spectral-clustering". Now, with 7 years distance, I guess that B) does not hold in general, but only for more specific objectives, like in their proof, which provides an additional symmetry of their objective function (via symmetric matrix K in their proof).

Comment: Hi there, I wonder did you figure out where to find relevant materials that has solution to the problems? Particularly with only symmetric constraint. Thank you